# What type of query to execute (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have a table which contains Room_Name, Name_Of_Booker, Status, Date_Time. I want to show the management how busy can a room get.
There is 2 value what the Status can be, either can be Busy or Empty. The Date_Time is a timestamp inserted like '2021-02-18 01:35:40'.

So a record in the table looks something like:

```
Rooom_Name | Name_Of_Booker | Status | Date_Time
------------------------------------------------------------
Room 05    | exampleName2   | Busy   |  2021-02-18 08:00:00 
Room 06    | exampleName1   | Busy   |  2021-02-18 09:15:00  
Room 06    | exampleName1   | Empty  |  2021-02-18 10:30:00         
Room 06    | exampleName3   | Busy   |  2021-02-18 10:30:00 
Room 05    | exampleName2   | Empty  |  2021-02-18 10:45:15 
Room 05    | exampleName4   | Busy   |  2021-02-18 11:00:00 
Room 06    | exampleName3   | Empty  |  2021-02-18 12:00:30 
Room 05    | exampleName4   | Empty  |  2021-02-18 14:30:00
```

So what I think of is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM loc_hist WHERE Location='Room06' AND Date_Time LIKE '2021-02-18%';
```

After running this query I get back 10 records which is perfect, now I wonder how to count the time the Room was busy for another row I mean all the time when the room was busy. Let's say the room gets "Busy" Status at 2021-02-18 09:00:00 and stays like that for 2021-02-18 12:00:00 at that time it gets "Empty" Status and stays empty till 2021-02-18 17:00:00.

So when I ran the query whith a date time like for today it will return me the last 24 hours result.

So what I need from that is:

```
Rooom_Name |     Busy    |   Empty     | //example result for 2021-02-18 should look something like because the qry looks between actions made between 2021-02-18 00:00:00 and 2021-02-18 23:59:59
----------------------------------------
Room 05    |   06:15:45  |  17:44:15   |
Room 05    |   02:45:30  |  21:14:30   |
```

Can I accomplish that with query? If so how?

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?

Comment: Is Date_Time a char/varchar column? Use timestamp data type instead.

Comment: I use MySql for this project.
The Date_Time field is datetime type.

Comment: Note that the SQL tag excerpt asks you to add the RDBMS as a tag to your Question. People do not watch for this in comments, they watch tags. If you're using MySQL, please add the tag. Any clarification as a result of a user asking in a comment, should go into your Question as an edit.

Comment: Thank you @Scratte for the heads up!

Comment: No problem :) I'm remove my comment shortly :)

Comment: It's not necessary I think, so other people who see this can, learn from it, to use the corresponding tag related to the question